# Wont link on the Page PHP

Tags: php, mobile-devices

I programm a website with php etc.

Now I want to show one page for Dektop user and another Page for Mobile User.

I start with the index.php.

I also get the "Desktop" by the echo on my site but the it doesn't link to the next page.

I also tried to put the Site in doublequotes but it doesn't work. 
The mbile_detece.php is also on the server.

```
<?php
    include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();

    // Check for any mobile device.
    if ($detect->isMobile()){
    echo "mobile";
    }else{
    echo "Desktop";
    header('Location:http://mysuperduperwebsite.de/Superduper.html');
    exit;

    }

    ?>
```

edit:

Now I tried this but nothing helps, no output before the header nothing and it wont work.

```
   <?php $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
{header("Location:http//example1111.de/mobil.php");}else{
header("Location:http//example111.de/desktop.html");    
}?>
```

This is my whole file but it wont work :(

Comment: Try looking into responsive webpages, it often is [better](http://www.webstarsltd.com/blog/why-responsive-web-design-is-important) than multiple separate websites or webpages.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are mixing PHP and javascript code. The window.open() sentence is javascript so if you want to use javascript you should echo it surounded by the 'script' tags:

```
echo "<script>window.open('http://mysuperduperwebsite.de/Superduper.html');</script>";
```

If you preffer redirection using PHP you have to use headers instead:

```
header('Location:http://mysuperduperwebsite.de/Superduper.html');
```

Comment: Check the error.log in your server, i think it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use javascript code in PHP. You should use http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php function. make sure you don't echo(output) anything before using `header()`

```
if ($detect->isMobile()){
    //echo "mobile";
    }else{
    //echo "Desktop";
    header('Location:http://mysuperduperwebsite.de/Superduper.html');
    exit;

    }
```